# What purpose do chests serve?

Tags: minicraft

I see that in Minicraft, you can create chests.  I assume these act as storage containers, but I don't understand the purpose of them.  So far, there seems to be no limit to what I can carry and as death is permanent, there seems to be little value in squirreling things away.

So why do chests exist at all?

Answer (score 7):

I think they exist as item organizers for now. Dunno if the dev plans to do anything else in the future.

Comment: What's the point of organizing my items, though?  If there's no limit to what I can carry and the crafting interface picks materials itself, the only thing I really need to organize is what I *want* to carry, which chests don't help with.  :-)

Comment: @BenBlank: To just clean out your inventory more so you can use some items easier, maybe?

Comment: To this end. Remember that he "created" this game in just 48 hours, assuming of course that he followed the rules and didn't have any of this done before hand. So if I had to guess, I would say that it is very likely that he could have intended for there to be a "respawn" system that he didn't have time to implement so he cut it. With a strict 48 hour deadline, he may have cut a lot of things. I wouldn't expect him to spend time adding more things in either.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing how there is no way to drop items on the ground, I would assume they are just there to store items you don't need.

For example, when you get a stone pickaxe, your wooden pickaxe would become obsolete. To help clear out your inventory a bit and make browsing the items you need easier, you could place the wooden pickaxe inside a chest.